# GENERATED ALWAYS AS at MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have already used `GENERATED ALWAYS AS` when creating new tables. However, when I try to `UPDATE TABLE` an already existing table with this computed/generated column I keep on getting a 1064 error. I have also tried with the `ALTER TABLE` option, but haven`t had any success either.
Sample:

```
UPDATE TABLE crecimiento_pib
SET País GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT(CountryName,' ',CountryCode));
```

Thanks for the help you can provide!

Comment: 1064 error is a syntax error. Are you trying to add a computed column to an existing table?

Comment: `UPDATE` is for modifying rows, not for modifying tables (e.g. adding columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to add a computed column to an existing table, the syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE crecimiento_pib
ADD COLUMN País varchar(200) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT(CountryName, ' ', CountryCode));
```

with an appropriate size defined by the length of the `CountryName` and `CountryCode` columns (which you haven't shown).